# Apache Spark difference between two RDDs

Tags: groovy, apache-spark

Say I have this example job (in Groovy w/ Java API):

```
def set1 = []
def set2 = []
0.upto(10) { set1 << it }
8.upto(20) { set2 << it }
def rdd1 = context.parallelize(set1)
def rdd2 = context.parallelize(set2)

//What next?
```

How do I get a set that is the delta between the two? I know that `union` can create a RDD that has all of the data in those RDDs, but how do I do the opposite of that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you just want a set subtraction [subtract](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#subtract(org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD)) would be an answer. If you want the "outer" collection try:

```
rdd1.subtract(rdd2).union(rdd2.subtract(rdd1))
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you're looking for something like this:

```
rdd1 = A, B
rdd2 = B, C
```

The result you're looking for is `A, C`?

An easy way of doing this would be:

```
rdd1.union(rdd2).subtract(rdd1.intersection(rdd2))
```

Comment: This will result in an empty collection... , won't it?

Comment: You're right - I meant intersection not union, see edit :)