# How to compare two RDDs using scala?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have two RDD like as `RDD[(String, String, DataTime, Int, Array[Byte])]`, Let us called `Rdd1` and `Rdd2` and I would like to compare between `Rdd1` and `Rdd2` with each and every tuple values and If not match then store in new Rdd. I use Spark on Scala.

For example:
consider output of Rdd's are:

```
 data = ((student1,XII,2016-09-11T00:00:00.000Z,1,0x0a130a0942553030303730333510ba1118f92120000a130a0942553030303730333510ba1118f92120001), 
         (student1,XII,2016-09-11T00:00:00.000Z,2,0x0a130a0942553030303730333510ba1118f92120000a130a0942553030303730333510ba1118f92120002),
         (student2,XII,2016-09-12T00:00:00.000Z,2,0x0a130a0942553030303730333510ba1118f92120000a130a0942553030303730333510ba1118f92120004),
         (student3,XII,2016-09-13T00:00:00.000Z,4,0x0a130a0942553030303730333510ba1118f92120000a130a0942553030303730333510ba1118f92120005)) 
 data2 = ((student1,XII,2016-09-11T00:00:00.000Z,1,0x0a130a0942553030303730333510ba1118f92120000a130a0942553030303730333510ba1118f92120001),
          (student1,XII,2016-09-11T00:00:00.000Z,2,0x0a130a0942553030303730333510ba1118f92120000a130a0942553030303730333510ba1118f92120002),
          (student2,XII,2016-09-12T00:00:00.000Z,2,0x0a130a0942553030303730333510ba1118f92120000a130a0942553030303730333510ba1118f92120004))
```

and also consider the partition key as

```
case class Student(name: String, class: String, dob: DateTime)
```

I want to check every entry(as well all field values) in `rdd1` should exist in `rdd2`, If not then store in new Rdd. 
In above example output will be:

```
 val resultRdd = ((student3,XII,2016-09-13T00:00:00.000Z,4,0x0a130a0942553030303730333510ba1118f92120000a130a0942553030303730333510ba1118f92120005))
```

Comment: So, that's your problem. What have you tried? What is your specific question?

Comment: I recommend reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31275850/apache-spark-difference-between-two-rdds

Comment: Have a look also here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37969286/comparing-two-rdds